# Can't share my ad account with bm partner through facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I need a help from an expert in Facebook Graph API.

I have the following problem with this function: Business to Business.
Specifically with this action: Grant Access to Assets for Another Business Manager

I can't share my ad account with my business manager partner, the graph api returns the following error: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

But I have all needed permissions:
"ads_management",
"ads_read",
"business_management"

Here the details of request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_733605894747225/agencies?business=377343377466914&permitted_tasks=ADVERTISE&access_token=)

Here the response of request:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,
"fbtrace_id": "A6-J0smfgkDt3Qkn1jm4zHs"
}
}

I am missing something? Maybe needed other permissions?

Thank you very much.

---

Tried this request:

https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_733605894747225/agencies?business=377343377466914&permitted_tasks=ADVERTISE&access_token=)

Here the response of request:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,
"fbtrace_id": "A6-J0smfgkDt3Qkn1jm4zHs"
}
}

But I'm expecting an "ok" status.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution?